# QuerySet filter get None column value, but in face it's not None

Tags: python-2.7, django-models

i have a piece of data in mysql, which has a column named create_time, and its value is 0000-00-00 00:00:00.000000. I check it in Navicat.
the table models:

```
class Meta:
        db_table = 'region_info'

    region_id = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True, help_text=u"region id")
    region_name = models.CharField(max_length=32, unique=True, help_text=u"数据中心名称")
    region_alias = models.CharField(max_length=32, help_text=u"数据中心别名")
    datacenter_env = models.CharField(max_length=20, help_text=u"数据中心所属环境", default='production')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=256, help_text=u"数据中心API url")
    wsurl = models.CharField(max_length=256, help_text=u"数据中心Websocket url")
    httpdomain = models.CharField(max_length=256, help_text=u"数据中心http应用访问根域名")
    tcpdomain = models.CharField(max_length=256, help_text=u"数据中心tcp应用访问根域名")
    token = models.CharField(max_length=40, null=True, blank=True, default="", help_text=u"数据中心token")
    status = models.CharField(max_length=2, help_text=u"数据中心状态 0：编辑中 1:启用 2：停用 3:维护中")
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, help_text=u"创建时间")
    desc = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True, help_text=u"数据中心描述")
    scope = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="private", help_text=u"数据中心范围 private|public")
    ssl_ca_cert = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text=u"数据中心访问ca证书地址")
    cert_file = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text=u"验证文件")
    key_file = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True, help_text=u"验证的key")
```

when i use `RegionConfig.objects.filter` get my data, i find the property create_time is None,just like:

```
>>> region = RegionConfig.objects.filter(region_name="rainbond")
>>> print len(region)
1
>>> r = region[0]
>>> print r.datacenter_env
test
>>> print r.create_time   
None
```

i want to know why it's None.

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of options that will help you for this

- [`auto_now_add`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now_add) - *Automatically set the field to now when the object is first created*
- [`auto_now`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.DateField.auto_now) - *Automatically set the field to now every time the object is saved*

So you'd use these on your model like this;

```
class RegionConfig(models.Model):
    create_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    modified_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

A caveat to these is that they don't show up in admin because they become readonly fields, so in an admin class, you need to define;

```
readonly_fields=('create_time', 'modified_time')
```

Docs for [`readonly_fields`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.readonly_fields)

Comment: it's used to have ```auto_now_add=True```,but also doesn't work.

Comment: The question is that create_time is not None, but use filter i get a None value.